# OBJ format and Flat vs Smooth Shading

Tags: opengl-es, blender

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 and working on converting an OBJ export from Blender into some binary files containing vertex data. I actually already have a working tool, but I'm working on changing some things and came across a question.

Even with Smooth shading, it seems that with correct normals (perpendicular to the face plane) it achieves a flat appearance for faces. With Smooth shading enabled and the proper normals (simply via edges marked as sharp in Blender and an edge-split modifier applied), I can get the affect of smooth parts and sharp edges.

Where I'm going with this brings 2 questions.

1. Are the "s 1" or "s off" lines where smooth or flat shading is denoted in the OBJ file completely unnecessary from a smooth shading and use of normals standpoint?
2. When actually set to Flat shading in OpenGL, are normals completely ignored (or just assumed to all be perpendicular to the faces)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a vertex to look smooth, its normal has to be the average of the adjacent face normals (or something the like), but not perpendicular to the face plane (except if you meaned the average plane of all its adjacent faces).

GL_FLAT means, the color of a face is not interpolated over the triangle, but taken from a single triangle corner (don't know which, first or last). This color comes either from vertex colors or vertex lighting, so in fact you get per-face normals, but this is not neccessarily the faces direction, but the normal of a corner vertex.

If you got per vertex normals in the OBJ file you do not need the s parts. But you can use these to compute vertex normals. The s parts are the smoothing groups and are to be interpreted as 32bit bitfields. So there are actually 32 different smoothing groups and every face can be part of more than one. So all faces after an "s 5" line are part of smoothing groups 1 and 3 (first and third bits set). When two neighbouring faces are part of the same smoothing group, the edge between them is smooth (vertices share normals). This way you can reconstruct the neccessary per-vertex normals.

Comment: There is nothing in the OBJ spec that says smooth groups should be interpreted as bitmasks, but its quite convenient to use them this way so I can see why a game engine might treat them this way.

Comment: @ideasman42 Hmm, maybe I got this from the 3DS-format, because there they are definitely used this way. When just taking them as smooth group ID you cannot get one face to belong to multiple groups.

Comment: Shouldn't `all faces after an "s 5" line are part of smoothing groups 1 and 3` be `[...] smoothing groups 1 and 4` ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle No, the 1st and 3rd bits are set, `5 = 2^0 + 2^2`.

Comment: `= 1 + 4`, I meant : `smoothing groups 1 and 4` as you can't have non power of 2 smoothing groups - How do we misunderstand ? :) IE. 7th bit set is `2^7 = 128` which is smoothing group 128 (`s 128`). Is this not correct ?

Comment: Problem being : how would you interpret a "s 3" statement then ? Smoothing group 3 breaks down as well to `2^0 + 2^1` which would mean "s 5" belongs to "s 1" and "s 2".

Comment: I need to make sure of that because I am implementing a normal creation routine that takes bitwise groups into account. I have a test model exported from MAX that only have power of 2 smoothing groups, I don't think it is a coincidence. I just wanted to have your thoughts on this as you seem more experienced on the topic =)

Comment: @PinkTurtle I don't know what you mean. `s 3` means the face belongs to smoothing groups 1 and 2 (1st and 2nd bits set). So a face with `s 5` and one with `s 3` share a smoothed normal because they belong to a shared smoothing group (1). But at the same time they also belong to additional different smoothing groups each. The fact that a face can belong to multiple smoothing groups is the whole point of interpreting it as bitfield rather than IDs. This allows for quite flexible smoothing rules.

Comment: I mean `s 3` belongs to `1` & `2` and `s 5` belongs to `1` and `4`. Simple as that. You can't break down smoothing groups into non power of 2 smoothing groups - which is what you stated with `"s 5" line are part of smoothing groups 1 and 3` which makes no sense.

Comment: Though, in most practical cases you will probably find that smothing groups are largely self-contained, meaning faces usually just belong to a single smoothing group. This would result in mostly powers of 2 being used as smoothing group bitfields.

Comment: @PinkTurtle I still don't get it. `s 5` means smoothing groups 1 and 3, because bits 1 and 3 are set. There are 32 distinct smoothing groups and the ones the faces belong to are represented by the bits set in the number after the `s`. What I call "smoothing groups" are the actual 32 smoothing groups from 1 to 32, *not* the number after the `s`, which is just the denotation of *which* of those 32 smoothing groups are activated.

Comment: I assumed `s 32` is smoothing group `32` but in your view it's smoothing group `5` - is that correct ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle Yes. If you would just take the numbers after the `s` as distinct smoothing groups directly you couldn't have faces belonging to more than one group.

Comment: Sadly I don't have a MAX model to test/inspect at hand - as I believe it is a MAX specific implementation ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle As said, I'm not 100% sure if OBJ inteprets it that way, too (but think I read that once). But I know with certainty that 3DS does interpret it that way (and thus probably also MAX). But unfortunately *official* documentation on 3DS and MAX is a bit scarce, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the mode between gl_flat and gl_smooth doesn't seem to affect my rendering when I'm using per vertex normals. Your problem from what I can tell is that each face only has one normal. For smooth shading, each face should have three normals, one for each vertex, and they should all be different. For example, the normals of a cylinder, if projected inside of the cylinder, should all intersect at the axis of the cylinder. If your model has smooth normals, then an OBJ export should export per vertex normals. It sounds like you are probably assigning per face normals. As far as rendering in OpenGL-ES, the smoothing groups aren't used, only normals.